# SQL: WHERE not working with JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, actionlistener, jtree

i am using valueChanged() to set the selected JTree Node to JTable, but i notes that i got no result when using WHERE. and got whole result after deleteing WHERE.

```
 @Override
public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent tsl) {
    try {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) TestTree.getSelectionPath().getLastPathComponent();
     myTests_table.getModel();

        if (tsl.getNewLeadSelectionPath() != null) {
            if (node.isLeaf() != true) {
                //do nothing
            } else {
                String sql ="SELECT sub_group.name AS 'name', sub_group.price AS 'price'"
                        + "FROM sub_group"
                        + "WHERE sub_group.name = '"+node+"' "
                        + "ORDER BY sub_group.name ASC";

                pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                rs = pst.executeQuery(sql);
                while (rs.next()) {
                    myTests_table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
                }

                 System.out.println(node);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, node);
                yy.setText(tsl.getNewLeadSelectionPath().getLastPathComponent().toString());

            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error");
    } finally {
        try {
            rs.close();
            pst.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Some Error with connecting Database, Try again");
        }
    }
}
```

But when iam using this line

```
+ "WHERE sub_group.name = '"+node+"' "
```

i got empy table, so what is the wrong with.?!

Answer (score 1):

Code is not enough to check. Update total code or Do sysout and update results it may possible to see what is error

```
 String sql ="SELECT sub_group.name AS 'name', sub_group.price AS 'price'"
                    + "FROM sub_group"
                    + "WHERE sub_group.name = '"+node+"' "
                    + "ORDER BY sub_group.name ASC";
System.out.println(sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would guess the node variable doesn't contain the string value that you expect it does. Do you display the toString() representation of the node anywhere to verify the value?

Also, use a PreparedStatement when using SQL. The PreparedStament will format the SQL properly so you don't need to worry about the delimeters around your variables. Maybe something like:

```
String sql ="SELECT name, price FROM sub_group WHERE name = ?";
PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
stmt.setString( 1, node );
stmt.executeUpdate();
```

Also, I believe the convention is to use mixed case names for table and columns.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of **=** (equals operator) use **like**

```
String sql ="SELECT sub_group.name AS 'name', sub_group.price AS 'price'"
                        + "FROM sub_group"
                        + "WHERE sub_group.name like '"+node+"' "
                        + "ORDER BY sub_group.name ASC";
```